La api key de mi app de react en vercel queda como undefined
Tengo este problema:
Mi web personal está hosteada en vercel. Integre resend para enviarme un email cuando me contactan, si uso la apikey directamente anda perfecto, pero cuando la guardo como variable de entorno en vercel, la toma como undefined, solo me toma la api key despues de que me devuelve la respuesta de que fallo porque esta undefined.
Supongo que debe ser algo asíncrono que no me carga la la variable antes de hacer el llamado. mi backend  lo despliego en vercel en el mismo proyecto que el front, funcionar funciona bien solo no me toma el apikey antes de hacer el llamado.
Mi backend es este:
import {Resend} from 'resend';

export default async function sender(req, res) {
    const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const {body} = req;
        const { error } = await resend.emails.send({
            from: 'Minombre <contacto@aaa.com>',
            to: ['aaa@gmail.com'],
            subject: 'Nueva consulta desde la web',
            html:  `<strong>${body.consulta}</strong>`,
        });
        if (error) {
            return res.status(403).send({error});
        }
        return res.status(200).send("Mensaje enviado, me pondre en contacto contigo a la brevedad.");
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
        return res.status(405).end(`Método ${req.method} no permitido`);
    }
  }

Y el front este:
const enviarEmail = async () => {
        setLoader2(true);
        const consulta = `${nombre} (${email}), quiere hacerte una consulta sobre "${asunto}": ${mensaje}`
        try {
            const config = {
                method: "post",
                url: "/api/send-email",
                json: true,
                data: { consulta },
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            };
            const response = await axios(config);
            setStatus(response.data);
            setShowStatus(true);
            setLoader2(false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data)
            setStatus('Error al enviar el correo');
            setShowStatus(true);
            setLoader2(false);
        }
    }

El problema es que no se como puedo hacer que me tome la api key.

Hay algunas situaciones que debes considerar, como por ejemplo si se esta usando el directorio src, o si se necesita cargar la variable de entorno fuera del runtime de nextjs. Revisa estos puntos y comenta si encontraste la solución
